# Trouble understanding a common vector calculus example

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

I have difficulty understanding the following vector calculus example. Text can be found [here](http://www.nhn.ou.edu/~shaferry/41832005_files/l9.pdf). It is the 5th Q&A -- starting with equation (31.1035).It concerns finding the vector potential of a current loop.

I get the argument up to $$\vec A=\frac{\mu I}{4\pi r^3}\oint \vec r'\cdot \vec r \,\,\,d\vec l'$$.
But I don't understand why $$\oint \vec r'\cdot \vec r \,\,\,d\vec l'=\left(\int d\vec a\right)\times \vec r$$

***[ADDED]***: Definitions of the terms:

This describes a current loop, with a current $I$ flowing in it.

$\vec r$ is the position vector of an arbitrary point in space. $\vec r'$ is a position vector of a point on the loop. $d\vec l'$ is an infinitesimal line element along the loop.

$\vec A(\vec r)$ is the  vector potential, given by $$\frac{\mu I}{4\pi}\oint \frac{d\vec l'}{|\vec r'-\vec r|}$$
The above expression is obtained by Taylor expanding this definition.

$d\vec a$ is an infinitesimal area element of the enclosed area in the loop with direction pointig out of the surface enclosed by the loop. So that $$\int d\vec a$$ is the area enclosed by the loop times the unit vector $\hat n$ pointing out of the plane (supposing the loop is planar...)

---

The first thing I tried is the vector triple product identity 
$$(\vec r'\cdot \vec r )\,\,\,d\vec l'=\vec r\times(d\vec l'\times \vec r')+(\vec r\cdot d\vec l')\vec r'$$
The first term looks like it's doing the right sort of thing, but I don't see why the second term vanishes (or fits in) ...Maybe I have missed out something quite obvious?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  It might help if you more fully defined your terms so that those who may help you don't have to ask all sorts of questions of you.

Comment: @RonGordon: yup, added!

Comment: and what is $d \vec{a}$?

Comment: @RonGordon, oops, added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression relates a loop integral with an area integral, so it has to be related to Green's theorem.